# Loading Large Data in Vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, flat-file

I have large amount of tab delimited Flat File Table. I want to load all data in a 2D vector Container in Quicker time. I have given my code below. I checked my code with Ofast, Os and O2 Complexities. But It will take nearly 20 Seconds to load 100,000 records with 4 columns. But I want to load 500,000 records within 1 Second. How can I achieve it. ?

```
typedef vector <string> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> table_t;

fstream& operator >> ( fstream& ins, record_t& r_record )
  {

  r_record.clear();

  string s_line;
  getline( ins, s_line );

  stringstream ss( s_line );
  string s_field;
  while (getline( ss, s_field, '\t' ))
    {

        r_record.push_back( s_field );
    }


  return ins;
  }


fstream& operator >> ( fstream& ins, table_t& t_data )
  {

  t_data.clear();


  record_t r_record;
  while (ins >> r_record)
    {
    t_data.push_back( r_record );
    }


  return ins;  
  }

    fstream fs("somesamplefile.txt",ios::in);
    table_t table;
    fs>>table;
```

Time Difference is :

```
Os      22.860000 Seconds
Ofast   21.320000 Seconds
O2      22.660000 Seconds
```

Comment: Do you know the size up front? If so you could call `reserve()` and avoid some reallocations.

Comment: Actually I am not sure How many records the table contains ? It may have over 600,000 records also. How could I use that reserve() function for random amount of records ?

Comment: If you don't know there is really no point in calling reserve. Can you use a linked list?

Comment: Yes I can. But is there any other standard containers for Linked List ?

Comment: What hardware, OS, etc. are you using?  On my system (Linux, 64-bit, 3GHz), your existing code loaded 500K rows of 4 columns in 0.7 seconds.  Total file size 9.8 MB (how about yours?).

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit , Kernel Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae , 4 GB Ram, 2.80 GHz, 100K rows of 4 Columns. File Size 2.1 Mb

Comment: OK well, I tried on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit, 100K rows of 4 columns, file size 2.0 MB, and it runs in 0.2 seconds *without optimizations enabled.*  The performance discrepancy here is huge.  Is your system a regular desktop or something special?  Have you tried profiling?

Comment: regular desktop itself. What about Profiling ? I don't have any Idea about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux  - but I suggest you can also try writing a "C" version of the same code, using `fopen()` and `fgets()` instead of `fstream` and `getline()`.  You can still use `vector` and `string` to store the data, but you may find the C++ iostream overhead is hurting you.

Comment: Dunno what the issue is. MacBook Air i7 duo-core 4gB, OSX 10.9.5 clang 3.5, release-build (O2) I pull a 9.2MB 500,000 4 columns file with your existing code in ~514ms. Full-debug pulls 1340ms. Something on that system is heinous, with times 15x debug and 40x release.

Comment: This is my Compiling Code.
g++ -Wall -Ofast -g -std=c++0x vectortab.cpp -o vecttab

Comment: I use Valgrind to run My code. 
valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes  ./vecttab > debug.txt 2>&1

Comment: @ WhozGraig . Is it a 32 or 64 bit processor?

Comment: @SmithDwayne 64bit (mid 2011)

Comment: any body can test  this code in 32 bit Machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If your platform permits it - it probably does - try reading the entire file into a single  memory buffer, then from the buffer into your vector.

If your platform has memory-mapping - Linux, BSD, Mac OS X and Windows all do - it's faster, and uses less memory to memory-map a file than to use file I/O system calls.

Whether you use file I/O (like UNIX' read(2) system call), or mapping (mmap(2) on *NIX, I don't recall what the Windows equivalent is called), you'll avoid a great many system calls.  I expect getline does some buffering itself, but the buffering won't be that big.